# Remove Shared preferences key/value pairs

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I store some payment values in one Activity

```
SharedPreferences spreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
productId = spreferences.getString("productId", "");
purchaseToken = spreferences.getString("purchaseToken", "");
orderId = spreferences.getString("orderId", "");
```

Now I retrieve them in another one as

```
SharedPreferences spreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
productId = spreferences.getString("productId", "");
purchaseToken = spreferences.getString("purchaseToken", "");
orderId = spreferences.getString("orderId", "");
```

My question is to delete them in the second Activity after retrieving them.Thanks.

Comment: Seems you mistyped the storing part. Should have a SharedPreferences.Editor usage there

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use [`SharedPreferences.Editor remove (String key)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#remove(java.lang.String)) to do the same.

> where it marks in the editor that a preference value should be
>   removed, which will be done in the actual preferences once commit() is
>   called.
>
> Note that when committing back to the preferences, all removals are
>   done first, regardless of whether you called remove before or after
>   put methods on this editor.

---

So in your case you can use it like

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spreferences.edit();
editor.remove("productId");
editor.remove("purchaseToken");
editor.remove("orderId");
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Better use apply() than commit().

Comment: Clearing something can lead to data inconsistency. Apply is asynchronous. @Adi

Answer (score 8):

To store values in SharedPreference, use below code:

```
SharedPreferences spreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
Editor spreferencesEditor = spreferences.edit();
spreferencesEditor.putString("productId", "value of prodId");
spreferencesEditor.putString("purchaseToken", "value of purchaseToken");
spreferencesEditor.putString("orderId", "value of orderId");
spreferencesEditor.commit();
```

To remove specific value from SharedPreference, use below code:

```
SharedPreferences spreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
Editor spreferencesEditor = spreferences.edit();
spreferencesEditor.remove("productId"); //we are removing prodId by key
spreferencesEditor.commit();
```

To remove All values from SharedPreference, use below code:

```
SharedPreferences spreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
Editor spreferencesEditor = spreferences.edit();
spreferencesEditor.clear();
spreferencesEditor.commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove any values associated with a specific key using this,

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.remove("your_key");
editor.commit();
```

or

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(name, mode);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.remove(your_key) 
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this SharedPreferences.Editor.remove(orderId). But the compiler doesn't recognise the remove(String value) method:(

Answer (score 2):

To clear the SharedPreferences, use the [SharedPreferences Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)
In your case:

```
SharedPreferences spreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spreferences.edit();
editor.clear(); 
editor.commit();
```

Comment: I have other shared preferences values in my second activity. I only want to delete 3 of them. Not all of them.

Comment: Alright, then [remove()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#remove(java.lang.String)) would be the way to go. Remember to [commit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit())

Answer (score 0):

You need to do same like I am removing my preferences.

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = contextAct.getSharedPreferences("PREF_KEY", 0);
                    preferences.edit().remove("productId").commit();
                    preferences.edit().remove("purchaseToken").commit();
                    preferences.edit().remove("orderId").commit();


    Format : preferences.edit().remove("Your Key").commit();
```

This will clear your preferences.

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences spreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=spreferences.edit();
 editor.remove("productId");
 editor.remove("purchaseToken");
 editor.remove("orderId");
 editor.commit();
 // you can also use editor.apply(); instead of editor.commit(); using apply will handle the removing in the background
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
    preferences.edit().remove("productId").commit();
```